# Перевод из арабских в римские числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Начинающий только в пайтоне,помогите упростить програму,ибо понимаю что слишком много ифов,как это можно сделать проще?
Прога работает (1-3999) но выглядит просто ужасно

```
line='';
line=int(input(line));
print(line);
line2="";
tysyach=line//1000%10 #M
sot=line//100%10    #C
desyat=line//10%10  #L
odynych=line%10     #I

if(tysyach!=None):
        line2 = "M" * tysyach;
        print(line2);
if(sot !=None):
    if (sot == 9):
        line2 += "CM"
    elif (sot == 4):
        line2 += "CD"
    elif (sot > 4):
        line2 += "D" + "C" * (sot - 5)
    else:
        line2 += "C" * sot;
    print(line2);
if(desyat!=None):
    if (desyat == 9):
        line2 += "XC"
    elif (desyat == 4):
        line2 += "XL"
    elif(desyat>4):
        line2 += "L"+"X"*(desyat-5)
    else:
        line2+="X"*desyat;
if(odynych!=None):
    if(odynych==4):
        line2+="IV";
    elif(odynych>5 and odynych<9):
        line2+="V"+(odynych-5)*"I"
    elif(odynych==5):
        line2 += "V"
    elif (odynych == 9):
        line2 += "IX"
    else:
        line2+="I"*odynych;
print(line2);
```

Comment: что такое проще и лучше?
вы хотите чтобы она работала быстрее или код меньше места по объему занимал или как?

Comment: именно чтобы она не выглядела так громадно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваш код очень избыточный, для решения этой задачи достаточно хранить соответствия чисел в словаре, а затем, пока это возможно, представлять число в виде римских цифр, начиная с максимальной величины.

```
roman_numbers = {'M': 1000, 'CM': 900, 'D': 500, 'CD': 400,
                 'C': 100, 'XC': 90, 'L': 50, 'XL': 40,
                 'X': 10, 'IX': 9, 'V': 5, 'IV': 4, 'I': 1}


def to_roman(number):
    roman = ''
    for letter, value in roman_numbers.items():
        while number >= value:
            roman += letter
            number -= value
    return roman


print("1777 =", to_roman(1777))
```

Вывод:

> `1777 = MDCCLXXVII`

Answer (score 1):

Простое решение, которое перечисляет все значения для всех разрядов:

```
n = int(input())
print(''.join((
    ('', 'M', 'MM', 'MMM'                                      )[n // 1000 % 10], 
    ('', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM')[n //  100 % 10], 
    ('', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC')[n //   10 % 10], 
    ('', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX')[n         % 10] 
)))
```

Можно заметить что все строки следуют одному образцу. Тогда так:

```
def digits(one, five, ten):
    return (
        '',              # 0
        one,             # 1
        one * 2,         # 2
        one * 3,         # 3
        one + five,      # 4
        five,            # 5
        five + one,      # 6
        five + one * 2,  # 7
        five + one * 3,  # 8
        one + ten        # 9
    )


n = int(input())
print(''.join((
    digits('M', '?', '?')[n // 1000 % 10], 
    digits('C', 'D', 'M')[n //  100 % 10], 
    digits('X', 'L', 'C')[n //   10 % 10], 
    digits('I', 'V', 'X')[n         % 10] 
)))
```